# Reducing display/well width to 10 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just starting with Bootstrap 3 - sorry if this is a stupid question.

The problem is that I don't want to use the whole width of the window for this particular form. It will always be filled on a desktop, but there's not enough information to fill up 12 columns, and it doesn't look good with the well covering all 12 columns.

I've got a layout with two columns of text boxes, like this (working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nkc2kd8/1/)):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">  <!-- left column -->
    <div class="row">     <!-- lots of rows in left col-->
      <!-- text box with label, width col-md-12 -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of left column -->

  <div class="col-md-6">  <!-- right column -->
    <div class="row">     <!-- lots of rows in right col -->
      <!-- text box with label, width col-md-12 -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of right column -->
</row>
```

The left column is a `col-md-6`, which contains rows of width `col-md-12`, and the right column is the same.

This looks ok, but the text boxes are too wide and the spacing between the left and right text boxes isn't quite right. So, I've changed the outer row to have 10 columns instead of 12 (by changing `col-md-6` to `col-md-5`). The text boxes now look good, but there's a big margin on the right. Bootstrap is producing 2 empty columns on the right, to make the 10 columns back up to 12.

Is there some way for me to cut out the two columns on the right, so that the well ends after the second column? I've tried both `.container` and `.container-fluid`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include an `offset` as part of your `container` class and change to `col-xs-10`.  This will make all page content fit within 10 columns.

```
<div class="container col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
```

Another way to do this via CSS is the below, which will affect all of your `container` classes.

```
.container {
  margin-left: 8.3333%; //the same margin as added by col-xs-offset-1
  width: 83.3333%; //the same width as added by col-xs-10
}
```

If you want this apply on all pages the CSS (second method) is preferred.  If it's just for a page or two then the first method is preferred.

**[Bootply Demo (1st option)](http://www.bootply.com/zpzLDRCHEz)** / 
**[Bootply Demo (2nd option)](http://www.bootply.com/FHqfBB1Pyu)**

(Also you have a typo in your question, it says `</row>` and it should say `</div>`).

Comment: Works a treat - thanks. I changed `xs` to `md` to match the rest, and it appears to be identical.

Comment: Sure thing...`md` will just make it so that this change applies on `md` and larger screens only.  It works too, just note that the site will be 12 wide on `xs` and `sm` screens.